# Checking whether my private members access my Google Site or not?

Tags: google-classic-sites

I am creating a private Google site page for a university project, and only my project's teammates can access the site. (of course) But I want to make sure that everyone participates by coming to the site. Is it possible to check whether your private members access the site or not?

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic logging of the specific users that visit your site. You can, however, get general metrics from Google Analytics. If you need to know whether people visit a page, you could try requesting an action by all users which is logged. For example, they could comment on the page or [submit a form](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=27248).